# How to assign ViewData value to JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to assign the value of a ViewData located in the Controller to a JavaScript variable in the front-end; and then add that variable to an AJAX URL API call.

Here is what I have so far:

1. Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewData["xTokenBackEnd"] = "IAMATOKEN";
                return View();
            }
```

2. Index.cshtml

```
    var xTokenFrontEnd = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["xTokenBackEnd"]));
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'https:&token=' + xTokenFrontEnd,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (result) {})
```

When running the app, I can see that the string of the variable is there at the end of the URL i.e. `https:&token=IAMATOKEN` however, I'm still not receiving anything through ajax. Is weird cause the value is there at the end of the URL but is almost as if it doesn't hold any real value. Maybe I need to do a conversion? If I take out the variable xTokenFrontEnd and put the real value IAMTOKEN then everything works fine so I'm thinking the error is in the way I'm adding xTokenFrontEnd to the end of the URL but not sure. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Examine the source for the rendered page (Index.cshtml) then show us that same section of js code.

Answer (score 0):

In you view get the value and assign to variable - for example:

```
string token = ViewData["xTokenBackEnd"];
```

then create hidden field with this variable example:

```
@Html.Hidden("hfToken", @token)
```

then you can call this value from jquery with:

```
$('#hfToken').val();
```

And finally use this value in ajax call

Comment: In JavaScript after I declare the variable `var token = ViewData["xTokenBackEnd"];` where should I place `@Html.Hidden("hfToken", @token)` ? if I try to place it in JavaScript it throws an error saying 'The name 'html' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: You dont declare variable in JavaScript. This is razor variable so you can reuse it when creating page. Post your view, so I can show you how.

Comment: I finally was able to make it work however I'm trying to keep the value of the token variable xTokenBackEnd hidden, so it looks like I won't be able to use ViewData or ViewBag. Unless there's a way to make those values hidden on the browser?